# Decay parameter of Adam optimizer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I think that Adam optimizer is designed such that it automtically adjusts the learning rate.
But there is an option to explicitly mention the decay in the Adam parameter options in Keras.
I want to clarify the effect of decay on Adam optimizer in Keras.
If we compile the model using decay say 0.01 on lr = 0.001, and then fit the model running for 50 epochs, then does the learning rate get reduced by a factor of 0.01 after each epoch?

Is there any way where we can specify that the learning rate should decay only after running for certain number of epochs?

In pytorch there is a different implementation called AdamW, which is not present in the standard keras library.
Is this the same as varying the decay after every epoch as mentioned above?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L508), `decay` adjusts `lr` per `iterations` according to

```py
lr = lr * (1. / (1. + decay * iterations))  # simplified
```

see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oNft.png) below. This is epoch-independent. `iterations` is incremented by 1 on each batch fit (e.g. each time `train_on_batch` is called, or how many ever batches are in `x` for `model.fit(x)` - usually `len(x) // batch_size` batches).

To implement what you've described, you can use a callback as below:

```py
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
def decay_schedule(epoch, lr):
    # decay by 0.1 every 5 epochs; use `% 1` to decay after each epoch
    if (epoch % 5 == 0) and (epoch != 0):
        lr = lr * 0.1
    return lr

lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(decay_schedule)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=50, callbacks=[lr_scheduler])
```

The `LearningRateScheduler` takes a function as an argument, and the function is fed the epoch index and `lr` at the *beginning* of each epoch by `.fit`. It then updates `lr` according to that function - so on next epoch, the function is fed the *updated* `lr`.

Also, there is a Keras implementation of AdamW, NadamW, and SGDW, by me - [Keras AdamW](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw).

---

[image]

---

*Clarification*: the very first call to `.fit()` invokes [`on_epoch_begin`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L925) with `epoch = 0` - if we don't wish `lr` to be decayed immediately, we should add a `epoch != 0` check in `decay_schedule`. Then, `epoch` denotes how many epochs *have already passed* - so when `epoch = 5`, the decay is applied.

Comment: Just want to clarify again, so if I use the standard Adam optimizer in keras Adam(lr=xx,decay=yy) does the lr now reduce after each batch size and each epoch?

Comment: Also what is the difference between this method and AdamW?

Comment: @Arjun `AdamW` only concerns itself with weight decays - whereas `AdamWR` uses _cyclic learning rates_; see my repo's README for a concise overview of both. You may also find [this thread](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/issues/18) useful. As for `decay`, in general, I advise against it, as most training is simply spent with a very small fraction of the original `lr`, eventually decaying entirely to zero.

Comment: @Arjun Since `decay` is independent of `epoch` - yes, it'll apply both on epoch end and on batch fit end, since "epoch end" happens at a "batch end". (But no, it doesn't "stack", i.e. happen twice on epoch end)

Comment: To me, this answer like similar others has a major disadvantage. Where and how we should specify the optimizer inside the ```.compile()``` method of the model. In your example above you specify ```LearningRateScheduler``` which is fine and the ```model.fit()```. But where is the ```model.compile()``` statement with the initialization of the *Adam optimizer*. Explicitely using the code above won't start the training process

Comment: They Link to the Source Code is sadly broken. Could you relink it ? I couldnt find it. I searched here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/adam.py

Answer (score 2):

Internally, there is a learning rate decay at each after each batch-size, yet not after each epoch as it is commonly believed.

You can read more about it here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/22/keras-learning-rate-schedules-and-decay/

However, you can also implement your own learning_rate scheduler, via a custom callback function:

```
    def learning_rate_scheduler(epoch, lr): 
        #Say you want to decay linearly by 5 after every 10 epochs the lr
        #(epoch + 1) since it starts from epoch 0
        if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
           lr = lr / 5

    callbacks = [
       tensorflow.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler, verbose=1)
    ]

    model.fit(...,callbacks=callbacks,...)
```

The above method works for all types of optimizers, not only Adam.

Comment: Actually, nevermind the latter half of my comment - it only applied to the old Keras API; from the source code, the callback does indeed apply recursively, so your original, except the conditional check, was fine - also updated my answer.

Comment: Pardon the mishaps - `epoch + 1` doesn't quite work either; to avoid an overly complicated expression, I just coded the condition explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I thought that maybe I don't remember well and reupdated it; thanks for repointing it out.