# In Keras, why is the attribute decay in SGD considered to be left in only for backward compatibility?

Tags: keras

Reading [Keras-SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD) I read the following.

> ..., decay is included for backward compatibility to allow time
> inverse decay of learning rate. lr is included for backward
> compatibility, recommended to use learning_rate instead.

Should decay no longer be used (doubtful) or is there another location to set it or is it replaced by another property? Why is Keras considering 'decay' only to be "included for backward compatibility."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning rate decay is commonly handled using training callbacks like [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) and, more flexibly, [LearningRateScheduler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler)

The snippet in the documentation of LearningRateScheduler gives an example of how to implement exponential learning rate decay like in SGD:

```
# This function keeps the learning rate at 0.001 for the first ten epochs
# and decreases it exponentially after that.
def scheduler(epoch):
  if epoch < 10:
    return 0.001
  else:
    return 0.001 * tf.math.exp(0.1 * (10 - epoch))

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=100, callbacks=[callback],
          validation_data=(val_data, val_labels))
```

Properties like `decay` and `lr` are a leftover from the era of the first version of Keras. Keras 2.x introduced a much cleaner API while remaining backwards-compatible.

Comment: This isn't anything like SGD's decay, which is iteration-based, not exponential, and does not have a 'delay'.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't marked for deprecation anywhere in docs or warnings, nor does it say "only", but it is suggestive of better available alternatives. One reason to avoid it is that a permanently decayed LR is seldom desirable (which is what it accomplishes), and it's hard to predict what a good value of `decay` should be ahead of time. From [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L805), it decays with `1 / (1 + iterations * decay)`. For alternatives and further details, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029254/10133797).