# AttributeError: Adam object has no attribute '_decayed_lr' when fine-tuning T5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am fine-tuning T5 LLM, with the model based on this Colab notebook from Google: [TF-T5- Training.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/snapthat/TF-T5-text-to-text/blob/master/snapthatT5/notebooks/TF-T5-Datasets%20Training.ipynb#scrollTo=dEutWnhiWRAq). My current model was defined like this:

```
class SnapthatT5(TFT5ForConditionalGeneration):
    def __init__(self, *args, log_dir=None, cache_dir= None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loss_tracker= tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='loss')

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, data):
        x = data
        y = x["labels"]
        y = tf.reshape(y, [-1, 1])
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            outputs = self(x, training=True)
            loss = outputs[0]
            logits = outputs[1]
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_variables))
        lr = self.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32)

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, logits)
        metrics = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        metrics.update({'lr': lr})

        return metrics

    def test_step(self, data):
        x = data
        y = x["labels"]
        y = tf.reshape(y, [-1, 1])
        output = self(x, training=False)
        loss = output[0]
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        logits = output[1]

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, logits)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
  def __init__(self, warmup_steps=1e4):
    super().__init__()

    self.warmup_steps = tf.cast(warmup_steps, tf.float32)
    
  def __call__(self, step):
    step = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
    m = tf.maximum(self.warmup_steps, step)
    m = tf.cast(m, tf.float32)
    lr = tf.math.rsqrt(m)
    
    return lr
```

My training process looks like this though (I'm doing it with Google Colab):

```
learning_rate = CustomSchedule()
# learning_rate = 0.001  # Instead set a static learning rate
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

model = SnapthatT5.from_pretrained("t5-base")
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

epochs_done = 0
model.fit(tf_train_ds, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=steps, callbacks=callbacks,
          validation_data=tf_valid_ds, validation_steps=valid_steps, initial_epoch=epochs_done)
```

However, when I tried to train the model (with TensorFlow 2.12.0), I got this error from Colab:     `AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_decayed_lr'`. I tried to change `_decayed_lr` to `lr`, but this was not recognized by Colab.

So, what could I do to get the decayed learning rate to the training step, and get the above problem fixed?

Comment: You should include your code for `CustomSchedule()`.

Comment: @mhenning I am sorry for forgetting the code for `CustomSchedule()` class, I got that in the question now!

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122245/in-keras-why-is-the-attribute-decay-in-sgd-considered-to-be-left-in-only-for-ba

Comment: @HoangCuongNguyen Hi, did you manage to solve this? I'm doing the same thing as you, but I havent found any soloutions. Thanks in advance.